# Flutter deeplink with unilinks plugin not working in android

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

I have specific config deeplink in AndroidManifest like this

```
            <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="unilink"
                android:host="myhost.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

And in my main.dart file :

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initDeepLinks();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> initDeepLinks() async {
  // Check if the app was opened by a deep link
  final initialLink = await uni_links.getInitialLink();
  handleDeepLink(initialLink);

  // Listen for subsequent deep links while the app is running
  uni_links.linkStream.listen((uri) {
    handleDeepLink(uri);
  });
}

void handleDeepLink(String? uri) {
  if (uri != null) {
    print(uri);
    // Process the deep link URI
    // Extract relevant information and navigate accordingly
    // For example, you can extract query parameters or path segments
  }
}
```

When I open url "unilink://myhost" in my web browser , my app not recognize url to open.

How can I handle deeplink correctly with unilinks plugin.

Comment: On which android version are you testing this?

Comment: I'm testing on Android 7.1

Comment: @RohitSuthar do you have any idea to solve this problem ?